# In datagridview ToList method is not available while taking the parameter from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

Again need your help here!

I am passing an object as a parameter from one for to another form, which contains the multiple values from multiple tables of database. After taking parameter in second form, I am trying to bind the values of object to a datagridview as a datasource, but the ToList method is not available to bind. Any idea on how should I bind the data?

In First form

```
        MembersList ml = new MembersList(mblist);
```

In Second form

```
    public MembersList(object mblist)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.mblist = mblist;

        dgvMembersList.DataSource = mblist;

    }
```

Comment: Why you passing `object` as parameter, why not using data type which used in the first form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToList` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` : `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList` so you need to add an using for the `System.Linq` namespace to be able to use it.

Comment: I am already using a namespace System.Linq... Error:'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to pass a IEnumerable<T> parameter to your MembersList constructor. You can't do ToList() on a object.